# The program can't start because MSVCR80D.dll

Tags: c, dll, dllimport

I have made a dll in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005. Then i am trying to use it in other project on the other computer in CodeBlocks IDE. Project is built, but when it use functions from dll i got an error: "The program can't start because MSVCR80D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstall the program to fix this problem". How to build my dll without dependences on MSVCR80D.dll or build in this  MSVCR80D.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run a debug version, which is linked to the debug version of the CRT. The latter is only available where VS has been installed. You should use the release version of your project on other machines (or manually copy all the dependent debug DLLs, which is not legal according to the license...).

Comment: maybe i gonna wrong way.. First, i am releasing dll with it's lib file. Then i copy .dll to the directory with .exe, including to the project code header file of dll and in a project properties setting path to .lib file. But no result.
Maybe i need to set up some properties in dll project in Visual Studio?

Comment: @dmigous Your build process sounds fine. The problem is with the runtime dependencies your VS built DLL carries. Any C/C++ program uses the CRT. In VS, the CRT (when dynamically linked) is in the MSVCR*.dll. However, Debug builds use different CRT DLLs than Release (The Debug ones end with "D"). Therefore, you should change the VS compilation mode to "Release", and use the DLL created in your release folder when running the CodeBlocks project. See [Set Debug and Release Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for help. The problem is solved by your suggestions and by turning off "Generate manifest" in Project properties -> Configuration properties->Linker->Manifest file. Actualy now i don't now how it helped, but it's work!