# The program can't start because it lacks MSVCP110.dll with C++ application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have created a C++ application with Visual-C++. It works well on my own machine. But when I try to execute it on another machine, it doesn't work. 
Knowing that I added the used dll files next to the executable and I'm using the release version.

I take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609096/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr80d-dll), but it doesn't help me.

**Error**

```
The program can't start because it lacks MSVCP110.dll on your machine. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Comment: Try installing [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679) on the target machine.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I like how you post the AU version of the website and I post the GB :p

Comment: @NeilKirk And the OP is in Tunisia....

Comment: Copying the file into the same directory as the EXE is enough.  Watch out for the file redirector on the 64-bit version of Windows, a 32-bit program needs to be installed to c:\program files (x86).  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to find out where Windows is looking for the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the two libraries `MSVCP110.dll` and `MSVCR110.dll` next to the executable.

Go to

```
Project settings -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library
```

And choose `DLL Multithreaded`.

Answer (score 1):

Your user needs to install the Visual Studio 2012 Runtime Redistributable from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679 (or you make an Installer for your product that does it automatically)

Alternatively go to your project settings, C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library = the same option as there but without the "DLL" in the name.

This will include the required library in your exe, but will make the exe larger. All your other libraries used by your project need the same option.

Comment: The is the same same problem.
Is it logical to ask to install the visual c + + on client machines?

Comment: @DinosaurOverflow Do you mean the client has to install Visual Studio C++ on their machine? No, that is not logical.